# Is there a way to read data from a Non-Apple Bluetooth Device with the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0, bluetooth, ios5

I really searched on this topic for a while now. Especially when iOS 3 was the latest software version on the iPhone.

I wonder if there is a possibility to connect the iPhone to an external device via Bluetooth using the SDK and retrieve measured data?

Thanks for your help!

Greeting!
mary

Comment: Sure its possible.  What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the Bluetooth device can masquerade as a Bluetooth keyboard, then it can send data to an iOS device encoded as keystrokes.

If the Bluetooth device is or can masquerade as a headset, then it might be able to send data encoded by an audio modulation scheme, such as FSK.  A matching modem/codec will need to be running in the iOS app.

For the newest iOS devices (4S) you can use the new Bluetooth LE protocol to send data (older Bluetooth data communication protocols are not available to apps unless you are in Apple's NDA MFi program).

Answer (score 0):

You have to look into the [MFi Program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/) by apple since you want your devices communicating. It provides support on using an external accessory with your iPhone, though you have to register/pay for it.