# Send data to BLE supported Non iOS device from iPhone using CoreBluetooth

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth

I would like to implement one iOS app . The app functionality is When I click on the `UIButton` in the iOS app , one LED should be ON in the Non `iOS` device (It is supporting the BLE) . So I know how to read the data from the Non iOS device using the **CoreBluetooth framework**. But dont know how to send data to Non iOS device . So My doubt is

1. Is there any thing we need to implement in the Non iOS device for Understanding the commands which are sent from iOS app ?.

For example I am sending One string `@"Start"`.
Any ideas or suggestion could be more helpful .

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11398596/is-there-a-way-to-read-data-from-a-non-apple-bluetooth-device-with-the-iphone

Comment: hey Adarsh Thanks for your reply, I am asking how to send data from iOS device to Non iOS device, but not reading data from Non iOS device.

Comment: Did you check the Apple Sample Code ? The one with the Temperature Sensor? You have to know what's the format of the data of the peripheral...

Answer (score 2):

Well for starters there is not magic way for you to send data to your non-iOS device, and for it to magically understand what it needs to do with it.

Check the BTLETransfer Example from the sample code in the developer portal it shows how to transmit data between two iOS devices. Furthermore, the peripheral role in the example is the one you have to mimic on your non-iOS device so it understands how to receive data your sending from a CoreBluetooth Central Manager.

In the example they use a rudimentary form of communication by setting a EOM flag (END OF MESSAGE) but it is effective and it works, it is not bulletproof though, but feel free to experiment with it. It will be useful if you have some knowledge on Network Transfer protocols  and packet transmission techniques, error checking, acknowledgement, synchronisation, etc. So you can build or chose one that suits your needs.